# How can I add an array item into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

How do I add a value from one array into another array to create a new array?

I have two arrays and I want to filter through **arrayTwo** find where `id === productID` from **arrayOne**. Then add `quantity` from **arrayOne** to **arrayTwo** so I can get a result such as **arrayThree**

```
arrayOne = [
  {
   productID: "DuWTLdYkpwF1DJ2x8SGB",
   quantity: 2
  },
]
```

```
arrayTwo = [
{
  id: "DuWTLdYkpwF1DJ2x8SGB",
  minQuantity: 1,
  name: "5 Shade Palette",
  price: "950",
  size: "30g",
  unitPrice: 950,
  },
]
```

**Wanted result::**

```
arrayThree = [
{
  id: "DuWTLdYkpwF1DJ2x8SGB",
  minQuantity: 1,
  name: "5 Shade Palette",
  price: "950",
  size: "30g",
  unitPrice: 950,
  quantity: 2,
  },
]
```

Comment: In other words, essentially, match the `productID` with the `id` and if matched, include the `quantity` prop to the matched element/s. Is that a fair understanding?

Comment: Perfect!! You nailed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one possible way to achieve the target.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// add "quantity" to existing products
const addDeltaToBase = (delta, base) => (
  // iterate over the "base" (ie, existing product array)
  base.map(
    ({ id, ...rest }) => {        // de-structure to access "id"
      // check if "id" is part of the delta (to update "quantity")
      const foundIt = delta.find(({ productID }) => productID === id);
      if (foundIt) {              // found a match, so update "quantity
        return ({
          id, ...rest, quantity: foundIt.quantity
        })
      };
      // control reaches here only when no match. Return existing data as-is
      return { id, ...rest }
    }
  )     // implicit return from "base.map()"
);

const arrayOne = [
  {
   productID: "DuWTLdYkpwF1DJ2x8SGB",
   quantity: 2
  },
];

const arrayTwo = [
{
  id: "DuWTLdYkpwF1DJ2x8SGB",
  minQuantity: 1,
  name: "5 Shade Palette",
  price: "950",
  size: "30g",
  unitPrice: 950,
  },
];

console.log(addDeltaToBase(arrayOne, arrayTwo));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added in the snippet above.

**NOTE**

- This answer will be able to handle both `arrayOne` & `arrayTwo` with multiple objects.
- It matches the `productId` with the `id` and when matched, it merges the `quantity` into the output (ie, `arrayThree`).
- It aims to be immutable so the input arrays may remain as-is

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two objects easily by using the spread operator:

```js
arrayOne = [
  {
   productID: "DuWTLdYkpwF1DJ2x8SGB",
   quantity: 2
  },
]

arrayTwo = [
{
  id: "DuWTLdYkpwF1DJ2x8SGB",
  minQuantity: 1,
  name: "5 Shade Palette",
  price: "950",
  size: "30g",
  unitPrice: 950,
  },
]

console.log({...arrayOne[0], ...arrayTwo[0]})
```

Use this in combination with your initial filter and you should have what you want. However I would advise to use 'find()' instead.

This will look something like this:

```
// Loop every item of one array
arrayOne.forEach( (product) => {
  // Find linked product
  let productToMerge = arrayTwo.find(p => p.productID === product.productID)

 // Let's merge them
 let newItem = {...product, ...productToMerge}
})
```

Now it's just a matter of pushing this newItem in an array to collect all new items.

[Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

[Find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?retiredLocale=nl)

Comment: This is almost what I need but it only works with one object in an array. How would it work if each array has a few objects in it.

Comment: I made an edit to show you how I would approach it.

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity is O(n^2) here. If the given arrays are really long, not the best option. Basically: for each item in `arrayOne`, find its pair in `arrayTwo` and merge them.

```
let arrayThree = arrayOne.map(first => {
    return {
        ...first,
        ...arrayTwo.find(second => second.id == first.productID)
    }
});
```

Comment: This is bringing the the first object as matched but not including the ``quantity``

Comment: `...first` part gets all keys from the first object. The mapped array will have the merged results.